# ¡Mira! y ¡fíjate! son intercambiables?

Tags: gramática

> ¡Fíjate! La hija de Resurrección está bailando.
>
> ¡Mira! La hija de Resurrección está bailando.

¿Son intercambiables?

Answer (score 1):

Los imperativos "fíjate" y "mira" pueden intercambiarse en casi todos los casos pero puede haber una sutil diferencia.

Los dos se usan para llamar la atención sobre algo o alguien, pero "fíjate":

1. parece requerir más concentración
2. puede referirse a un objeto más preciso y quieto

Entre:

> A. ¡Fíjate! La hija de Resurrección está bailando.

y

> B. ¡Mira! La hija de Resurrección está bailando.

(B) tal vez suene más natural porque la atención se focaliza en una escena en movimiento: la hija de Resurrección bailando. (Igualmente, se pude usar (A), sobre todo si se está mirando una foto.)

Así, diríamos:

> C. Fíjate en esta foto si la hija de Resurrección está bailando. (Implica más concentración y detalle, aunque también podríamos decir "mira".)

Además de referirse a la percepción con el sentido de la vista, ambos pueden denotar un proceso mental (similar a "considerar" o "tener en cuenta").

E. Fíjate que falta poco para el examen.

F. Mira que falta poco para el examen.